# Ruby On Rails ERB CSS Layout Question

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

I have a question with turning this html into erb.

```
<button name="support" type="button" value="Get Support" class="brightOrange">
<span>Get Support</span>
</button>
```

I've been trying to do something like this in rails.

```
<% form_tag get_support_path do %> 
    <%= text_field_tag :email, "Email:" %>
    <% submit_tag "Join", :class=>"brightOrange" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help in advance. Not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button_to "Get Support", {:action => 'support/get'}.
```

you can give HTML options also.

See following links for more details

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to
- http://snipplr.com/view/866/ruby-on-rails-form-helper-with-image-submit-button/
- http://blog.moertel.com/articles/2005/05/08/taking-the-unsafe-gets-out-of-rails

Comment: How would you put in the <span> though with the method?

Comment: :action => 'support/get' , What does this mean? Since there is no action called support/get, does this just go directly to the URL of suppor/get?

Comment: Hi ROR, yes, support/get is the support controllers get action. (Its not RESUFuly though). why you need a <span>Get Support</span> ??